# R : speed up multiple if statements

Tags: r, switch-statement

i have a dataframe (mydata) with 220k rows  and i want to do 8 if statements on 1 column(BRLABELS) for each row . Simple if / else if  procedure took  about 5 minutes and i just wanted to speed it up .

I tried the switch function way like this . 
At first i defined it

```
group_label<-function(x){
  switch(x,"15-19"=1,"20-24"=1,"25-29"=2,"30-34"=2,"35-39"=3,"40-44"=3,
         "45-49"=4,"50-54"=4,"55-59"=5,"60-64"=5,"ISCED 0"=6,"ISCED 1"=6,"ISCED 2"=6,"ISCED 3"=7,"ISCED 4"=7,"ISCED 5"=8,"ISCED 6"=8,0)}
```

and then used it in the for loop

```
for ( i in 1:k){
  x<-mydata$BRLABELS[i]
  mydata$group[i]<-group_label(x)}
```

The confusing part is that this method took about 15 minutes , while in theory the switch method is suited for multiple if statement .

Can someone explain why this is happening and maybe provide efficient alternatives?

Comment: Are you just trying to relabel `BRLABELS`? Please provide a small representative sample of `BRLABELS` and your desired output.

Comment: `recode` from the `car` package might be of use

Comment: a<-c("AT","AWNUMBR","15-19",5.6)
b<-c("AT","AWNUMBR","20-24",2.4)
c("AT","AWNUMBR","15-24",8)
aux<-rbind(a,b,c)                                                                                                      Im trying to recode one column while adding the values of another .And i did   , using ddply(mydata,~GEO +VAR +ANSWER +LABELS +BREAKDOWN +group ,summarise,VALUE=sum(VALUE))   after the for /if/else part  . Im just trying to make it quicker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end used the recode function of the the "car" package that James mentioned .

```
mydata$BRLABELS<-recode(mydata$BRLABELS,"c('15-19','20-24')='15-24';c('25-29','30-34')='25-34';c('35-39','40-44')='35-44'; c('45-49','50-54')='45-54';c('55-59','60-64')='55-64';c('ISCED 0','ISCED 1','ISCED 2')='ISCED 0-2';c('ISCED 3','ISCED 4')='ISCED 3-4';c('ISCED 5','ISCED 6')='ISCED 5-6'; else ='0'")
```

It is  eye-friendlier  than the for\if loop  and the difference in time amount is huge . 
Finally i added the column  i wanted (which was the final purpose ) using the plyr package.

```
ddply(mydata,~GEO +VAR +ANSWER +LABELS +BREAKDOWN +BRLABELS ,summarise,VALUE=sum(VALUE))
```

Thanks for the help guys

Answer (score 4):

You can copy / paste your code from switch to:

```
new_values <- c("15-19"=1,"20-24"=1,"25-29"=2,"30-34"=2,"35-39"=3,"40-44"=3, "45-49"=4,"50-54"=4,"55-59"=5,"60-64"=5,"ISCED 0"=6,"ISCED 1"=6,"ISCED 2"=6,"ISCED 3"=7,"ISCED 4"=7,"ISCED 5"=8,"ISCED 6"=8,0)
```

And update values with:

```
mydata$BRLABELS <- new_values[mydata$BRLABELS]
```

I assume BRLABELS are not factors (otherwise your code wouldn't work).

#### Update: Time test

```
group_label<-function(x){
  switch(x,"15-19"=1,"20-24"=1,"25-29"=2,"30-34"=2,"35-39"=3,"40-44"=3,
         "45-49"=4,"50-54"=4,"55-59"=5,"60-64"=5,"ISCED 0"=6,"ISCED 1"=6,"ISCED 2"=6,"ISCED 3"=7,"ISCED 4"=7,"ISCED 5"=8,"ISCED 6"=8,0)}

new_values <- c("15-19"=1,"20-24"=1,"25-29"=2,"30-34"=2,"35-39"=3,"40-44"=3, "45-49"=4,"50-54"=4,"55-59"=5,"60-64"=5,"ISCED 0"=6,"ISCED 1"=6,"ISCED 2"=6,"ISCED 3"=7,"ISCED 4"=7,"ISCED 5"=8,"ISCED 6"=8,0)

mydata <- 
  data.frame(
    BRLABELS = 
      sample(c("15-19","20-24","25-29","30-34","35-39","40-44",
               "45-49","50-54","55-59","60-64","ISCED 0","ISCED 1","ISCED 2","ISCED 3",
               "ISCED 4","ISCED 5","ISCED 6"), 
             10000, replace = TRUE ), 
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


mydata2 <- mydata




library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(times = 5,
  for_loop = for ( i in 1:nrow(mydata)){
    x<-mydata$BRLABELS[i]
    mydata$group[i]<-group_label(x)},
  direct = mydata2$group <- new_values[mydata2$BRLABELS]
  )


#     Unit: microseconds
#     expr            min         lq        mean     median         uq        max neval cld
#     for_loop 737247.663 765056.444 781973.1502 769505.576 814000.738 824055.330     5   b
#     direct      325.432    326.715    375.2092    344.249    387.012    492.638     5  a
```

Comment: and if i want to add the Values column of the old BRLABELS  by level of the new labels?

Comment: @AlexKarvouniaris You don't have to update the column. For example `mydata$BRLABELS_VAL <- new_values[mydata$BRLABELS]` will insert new column with values and leave the old BRLABELS.

Comment: Did you run a time test to verify this is faster?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Just did :) and yes - it is much faster.